# how to extract specified text in HTML using SGMLParser

Tags: python, html, tags, sgml

i create a class extended SGMLParser:

```
class URLLister(SGMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        SGMLParser.__init__(self)

    def start_title(self, attrs):
        pass

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print data
```

very very simple code. IMO `start_title` was invoked when it came across `<title>` tag, and `handle_data` was invoked when it came across normal text. now i want to extract the text between `<title>` and `</title>`, e.g.

```
<html><head><title>Webpage title</title></head><body>Simple text</body></html>
```

i want to print the `Webpage title` between `<title>` tag, but using `handle_data` tag i will output all the simple text including `Webpage title` and `Simple text`. how to simply output the text between `<title>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, you could just add a hard-coded check in `handle_data` like so:

```
def handle_data(self, data):
    tag = self.get_starttag_text().replace("<","").replace(">","")
    tag_words = tag.split(" ")
    if len(tag_words) > 0 and tag_words[0].endswith("title"):
        print data
```

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted exactly, and I'm sure there's a more elegant answer.